# FUNCION GREATEST() EN SQL

Tags: sql, function

MYSQL puede manejar una función `GREATEST()` la cual SQL no tiene, e intento cambiar la siguiente linea de código:

```
SELECT GREATEST(Efectivo,Cheques,Depositos,Tarjetas,Vales) 
INTO M FROM movcaja WHERE sys_pk=MovCaja;
```

Logró cambiarlo a esto:

```
SELECT @M = (SELECT MAX(M) FROM (VALUES (Efectivo),(Cheques),(Depositos),(Tarjetas),(Vales)) AS T(M)) , 
FROM movcaja WHERE sys_pk= @MovCaja;
```

Marcando el error de:

> ##Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetMetodoPago, Line 18
>   ##Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Todo para resolver la función siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMetodoPago() RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN 
DECLARE @E decimal(18,8);    
DECLARE @C decimal(18,8);    
DECLARE @D decimal(18,8);    
DECLARE @T decimal(18,8);
DECLARE @V decimal(18,8);    
DECLARE @M decimal(18,8);    
DECLARE @R VARCHAR(50);      
DECLARE @MovCaja INTEGER;
DECLARE @PkVta INT;
SELECT @MovCaja =  COALESCE(imovcaja,0)  FROM venta WHERE sys_pk= @PkVta;
if (@MovCaja=0) 
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @MovCaja = COALESCE(imovcaja,0) FROM venta WHERE AplicadoA= @PkVta;
END;

SELECT @M = (SELECT MAX(M) FROM (VALUES (Efectivo),(Cheques),(Depositos),(Tarjetas),(Vales)) AS T(M)) , FROM movcaja WHERE sys_pk= @MovCaja;      
SELECT @E = Efectivo, @C = Cheques, @D = Depositos, @T = Tarjetas, @V = Vales   FROM movcaja WHERE sys_pk= @MovCaja;      
IF @M=@E BEGIN SET @R = '01';END;    
IF @M=@C BEGIN SET @R = '02';END;    
IF @M=@D BEGIN SET @R = '03';END;    
IF @M=@T BEGIN SET @R = '04';END;    
IF @M=@V BEGIN SET @R = '08';END;    
ELSE SET @R = '99';    

RETURN @R;  
END;
```

Comment: Quita la coma antes del from ahí no va

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa coma antes del from no va ahi:

```
SELECT @M = (SELECT MAX(M) FROM (VALUES (Efectivo),(Cheques),(Depositos), 
(Tarjetas),(Vales)) AS T(M)) ,
FROM movcaja WHERE sys_pk= @MovCaja;
```